# How to import and use a font in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

So, I'm using the code below, but the font is not applying to my layout, what am I doing wrong?

```
@import url('https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans?family=Open+sans')

body {
   font-family: "Open sans"
}
```

When I inspect the element, it shows that the `font-family` is `Open sans` but the one that is rendered is `Times New Roman`.

And I guess that the font has been imported successfully.

[image: Print from inspect element]

[image: Print that the font was imported]

Comment: That url leads to a webpage to describe the font ... not to the CSS file you actually need. Where you get the instructions to include the font that way ?

Comment: @DaniP, hahaha, I didn't thing this way, thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

put this in your html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans?family=Open+sans"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">  use this instead and check for the Open Sans failure

Comment: font-family:'Open Sans';